# Using ANT to reverse a properties value then replace among files

Tags: java, javascript, ant

Experts,

1. In my program, there are properties files, JSP files and *.java files.
2. And those files will use a "domain name" for some actions.
   (I use "domain name" is because it looks like a domain name, for example: abc.abcnet.com or abc.com) 
   And action example is it will retrieve this "domain name" and look up to a LDAP structure
3. Follow the step 2 example, you may know in LDAP structure, it usually reverse the domain name (ex: ou=com , ou=abcnet, cn=abc ...)
4. My program will be deployed to different servers, and each server has a different LDAP node names
5. every time when I deploy my program to a different server, I need to manually update properties files, JSP files and java files with the correct "domain name"
6. And my customer would like me to automate the deployment tasks, and they want to only fill in "domain name" in a file (for example: every time before they deploy my code, they only edit a properties file, set Key=abc.abcnet.com )
7. Therefore I would like to know if it is possible that I can let my customer only modify a properties file and my ant task can read the value of key (ex: abc.abcnet.com) then reverse it.
8. And use this reversed string to replace among my program files.

I searched and looks like Javascript provides reverse function, but it can't read a local file directly.

I hope this time I explained a bit clear.

Any idea is appreciate.

Best Regards

Comment: Read multiple times but not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What did you try so far? And how it is related with JavaScript?

Comment: Experts, Sorry I am new to ANT task development.

Comment: I modified my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses Groovy for the script part - which you can substitute other languages based on the Ant documentation.  I have updated the solution to include setting a new property, ***domain***, with the reversed value.

```
<project name="StackOverflow" basedir="." default="reverse">

        <target name="reverse">
           <loadproperties srcFile="domain.properties"/>
           <!--<echo>${key}</echo> -->
           <script language="groovy">
              def components = key.split('\\.').reverse().join('.')
              def project = self.project
              project.setProperty('domain', components)
           </script>
    <echo>Reversed domain=${domain}</echo>
</target>

</project>
```

Output here

```
   Buildfile: c:\GroovyStuff\StackOverflowQuestion\reverse.xml

reverse:
    [echo] Reversed domain=com.abcnet.abc

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

and the property file - domain.properties

```
key=abc.abcnet.com
```

Comment: Hi Mikemil, I tested the code:<script language="groovy">
              def components = key.split('\\.').reverse().join('.')
              def project = self.project
              project.setProperty('IDENTIFIER', components)
           </script>
   <echo>"Reversed domain=${IDENTIFIER}"</echo>

And it reports error:
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: key for class: Script1

Any idea what did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you cut/paste my copy from the response? If the key is not defined, then uncomment the <echo> tag or make sure the <loadproperties> tag is there to load the properties file into properties.  The target I provided relies in the loadproperties tag to read the domain.properties file and it will create a property from each line in the properties file.

Comment: One other comment - to use Groovy, I put my groovy jar (groovy-all-2.2.1-indy.jar) in my ANT_HOME\lib folder.

Comment: If you can't get it working let me know, otherwise, if it works, please accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Mikmil, is there a specific to "accept" answer? you answer works.

Comment: I thinnk you just click the up-arrow on the answer and that should then add a green check mark.